# Redirect output of MATLAB verbose function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, verbose

I'm writing a MATLAB app which involves the `fminbnd()` function. The function is a bit slow (takes several seconds to complete) so I want to print status updates to the user. Naturally, I set the `'Display'` option of `fminbnd()` to `'iter-detailed'`, which is the intended solution.

When running the app from MATLAB (i.e. the `.mlapp` file) the verbose output of the function can be easily seen by looking at the console in MATLAB itself. Unfortunately, the users will get a standalone app, without the console. So, the verbose output will be hidden from them.

**Is there a way to display the output of the function in a textbox (or any other way) visible to the users of a standalone MATLAB app?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: An answer has been given to me on the mathworks forums. Sharing here in case anyone needs it: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2061522-redirect-output-of-matlab-verbose-function. As soon as I will verify that it works, I'll add it as a formal answer.

Comment: You can use [`evalc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) to capture the text that would normally be displayed on the command window, and then show that text on a textbox. However, you can only access the text once the function has finished, which is probably not what you want